# Loop through HTML checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, checkbox

I am trying to write with jQuery something that does the following.

When you click, let's say, on a paragraph, it checks to see if the checkbok is selected (checked), if it waits x amount amount of time and selects the next check box and so on.

The closest I got (not much, sorry) [you can see it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jXHTJ/1/).

In this example you have to click once for each check, I dont want this.

I need that when you click the `<p>` it:

- Checks,
- Changes,
- Checks,
- Changes(and so on)

If it is possible to loop through this, even better.

Thanks a lot in advance, I hope it is clear enough, if not, please ask!

EDIT: as @James said basically what I want is want is to

> continuously loop through the
>   checkboxes checking and unchecking
>   them

Comment: Do you mean automatically, on a timer, or how you have it?

Comment: No, it should be triggered by a click, but the a timer between each new "check if checkbox is checked", is this clear? thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').each(function(i) {
        var current = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() { current.attr('checked', !current.attr('checked'))}, i*500);
    });
});
```

Updated jsFiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jXHTJ/2/

UPDATE: To change the order on every click (as requested in the comments) so that the checkboxes are checked/unchecked in the order {1,2,3} then {2,3,1} then {3,1,2}, you can use the following code:

```
(function() {
    var startWith = 0;
    $('p').click(function() {
        var checkboxes = $(':checkbox');
        var numCheckboxes = checkboxes.length;
        checkboxes.each(function(i) {
            var current = $(this);
            var delay = (i + startWith) % numCheckboxes;
            setTimeout(function() { current.attr('checked', !current.attr('checked'))}, delay*500);
        });
        startWith = ++startWith % numCheckboxes;
    });
})();
```

Note that I'm encapsulating the code in an anonymous function that I immediately execute so that I don't pollute the global namespace with the startWith variable. Updated jsFiddle is here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jXHTJ/3/

Comment: That look quite good!! I´ll see if I can adapt it to my actual code, thank you very much!

Comment: @James thank you very much, but can you thing of a way to make it loop  like 1, 2 ,3 ,1 ,2 3.. etc? I cant get around this, thanks!!

Comment: James, thank you so much and I dont want to bother you any more, you've guided me more that enough, but what I actually ment was only one paragrapgh clickable that when you click it it goes through the check boxes like this: unselect first, select second, unselect second, select third, unselect third, select first and the cycle starts again... I really appreciate it!

Comment: So you want to continuously loop through the checkboxes checking and unchecking them? If so, you can use setInterval() rather than setTimeout().

Comment: Oh, thats interesting I'll give it a try!

Comment: @James, for some reason, I can't get it to waork but i'll keep trying, thanks for now!! :)